# User Specific App Settings

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I have started working with server side app settings and it would appear the default mechanics for a shared app is to save the app settings across the entire project scope; so if an individual makes changes to the app settings, those changes are reflected for all future users. This is not the ideal use in my specific case. I would like it if I could have different settings for each user, without them each adding separate instances of my custom HTML. Is this possible using server side settings, or will I need to look into using cookies to save the settings on each user?

Note: I've read the documentation on app setting scope (https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/settings-section-define-scope) but it doesn't appear as though "user" is an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue by prepending the user ObjectID to each setting value before I save or load it from the Rally servers. Here is the code for my user settings set/get functions:

```
setUserSetting : function(settingName, settingValue, callback) {
    var settings = {};
    settings[App.getContext().getUser().ObjectID + settingName] = settingValue;
    App.updateSettingsValues({
        settings : settings,
        success  : function() {
            App.setSettings(Ext.Object.merge(App.getSettings(), settings));
            callback();
        }
    });
},

getUserSetting : function(settingName) {
    return App.getSetting(App.getContext().getUser().ObjectID + settingName);
}
```

BTW, it seems kind of strange that I have to save the settings in the way I have. The "updateSettingsValues" function sets the settings on the *next* load of the app and the "setSettings" function sets it for the current runtime of the app. It's a strange way to have to do it, but it works.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround.  The main reason this currently works like this is because on a shared dashboard users other than the owner can only view settings- not edit them.  However it probably wouldn't be hard to add a new user settingsScope and enable those settings to be edited.  Feature request submitted.

Answer (score 3):

Conner, you're making a good argument for User-level settings for an app.
Unfortunately, we don't support that currently. The [settingsScope](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.app.AppSettings-cfg-settingsScope) option in AppSettings only supports the values app, project, or workspace.

Creating an instance of the app for each user (such as on their individual dashboard) is the best alternative I can think of. But as you mentioned, this is not ideal for you.